# Can a log file on the /var filesystem cause an application crash

Tags: logging, crash, filesystems, aix, stunnel

I am running AIX 7.1 on a Power processor and was installing the stunnel application to provide some secure connections for our SAP applications. I ran into an unusal problem. The AIX version of stunnel had to be upgraded because the version that I had been running was 4.56. My task was to upgrade to version 5.17. the upgrade seemed to go OK at first, but the next day it crashed and no one was able to use it, which was odd because it worked fine while testing the day before.

I became aware that the log files had gotten huge after we reverted to the previous version. We began to wonder if the huge logs files had caused stunnel to stop responding. However, my understanding was that a malfunctioning application would not be likely to cause a crash if the log files were stored on a separate filesystm even if the logs could not grow any larger. The systems in question are listed below:

```
    /dev/hd2         6815744   1163392   83%    58365     7% /usr
    /dev/hd9var      8388608   6646104   21%     1010     1% /var
    /dev/hd10opt    10485760   3120696   71%    38535     3% /opt
```

Our version of stunnel was installed under /opt and the log files under /var.

So could maxing out the space under /var where my logs were kept cause the application to freeze or crash?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.
The issue with application crash is not caused by the system, if it would then the complete OS would stop working since lot's of important services use /var to log their stuff.
Applications may crash if they can't write data to the logs. The reason might be that logs are actually important data, for audit reasons. In case of a security application, it's most likely that if something can't be logged then it's better to not do it.
There are many such applications which are well known to stop working in case filesystem where they write their data or logs get full.